# append items in an array does not work and postgresql does not permit to use select

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using a cursor, fetching one column *'email1'* table *'pepe_emails'* of 10 items.
Inside the loop I try to append the content fetched in an array. If I write *'select array_append (arr_emails, table_record::varchar);'* appears this message:

```
ERROR:  la consulta no tiene un destino para los datos de resultado
HINT:  Si quiere descartar los resultados de un SELECT, utilice PERFORM.
```

And if I use perform, as is suggested, the the item is not append in to the array. Here is my current and failed code:

```
do $$
declare
    cursor_emails cursor for
        select pepe_emails.email1
        from pepe_emails;

    arr_emails varchar[];
    table_record record;
    i integer := 0;

    begin
        raise notice 'Hola 1';
        open cursor_emails;
        loop
        raise notice 'Loop %', i;
        i = i + 1;
            fetch cursor_emails into table_record;
            raise notice 'Value: %', table_record;
            perform array_append (arr_emails, table_record::varchar);
            raise notice 'Value: %', arr_emails[-1];
        exit when not found;
        end loop;

    close cursor_emails;

    end;
$$;
```

> And this is the output of the code:

```
NOTICE:  Value: <NULL>
NOTICE:  Loop 1
NOTICE:  Value: (us_2.gmail.com)
NOTICE:  Value: <NULL>
NOTICE:  Loop 2
NOTICE:  Value: (us_3.gmail.com)
NOTICE:  Value: <NULL>

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the field of the record and then do a simple assignment. No need for `perform`:

```
arr_emails := arr_emails || table_record.email1;
```

Depending on the type of the `email1'  column, you might need to cast that to text:

```
arr_emails := arr_emails || table_record.email1::text;
```

You don't see any results because the variable is initialized to `null` and any expression involving `null` results in null. So you need to initialize the variable with an empty array:

```
declare
   ....
   arr_emails text[] := '{}';
```

---

You could however get rid of the whole function and simply use:

```
select array_agg(email1)
from pepe_emails;
```